# EntityFramework DataContext is not recognized

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, webforms

I'm moving a previously working application from a WebForms WebSite to Web App.  When I try to implement the entity framework reference, the system is not recognizing the entity model.  I have a data model saved as "CustomerSurveyDBEntities.edmx" and NuGet shows that I have EntityFramework v6.1.3 installed.  It shows System.Data.Entity is not currently being used in this scope.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
//...this is greyed out
using System.Data.Entity;
//...
//This is where my entity model is no longer recognized
using (CustomerSurveyDBEntities myEntities = new CustomerSurveyDBEntities())
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears to have been a scoping issue.  While the existing file structure of using an .edmx model within the App_Code folder worked with the legacy code, this issue was fixed by deleting the legacy model and adding a new code-first model into the project root.  A better explanation can be found here:

https://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/EF/Code-First-to-Existing-Database-EF6-1-Onwards-